# Wireguard with identical remote LANs: policy-based routing or network namespaces?

Tags: wireguard

I have a server with multiple WireGuard VPNs.
Each VPN is independant from others, no connections between them.

Some VPNs are connected to remote LANs with same address space. For example I have OFFICE_1 and OFFICE_2 both with 192.168.0.0/24.
I use LXC to create "virtual machines" hosting WireGuard, so identical remote LANs are not a problem because each WireGuard is on a separate virtual machine.
This solution is simple, but not handy regarding system maintenance.

I'm not used to other methods. Is policy-based routing, or network namespaces, or cgroups, or whatever, a better alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Using LXC VMs (or containers) for this is nice and simple (although you may have had to fiddle a bit with the firewall on the server to forward the WireGuard listen ports to the VM/containers).

---

But you could use policy routing for this as long as the server uses a different address in each WireGuard network (eg `192.168.0.1` for OFFICE_1, `192.168.0.2` for OFFICE_2, etc). If you use [wg-quick](https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/about/src/man/wg-quick.8) to start up each WireGuard interface on the server, you could add the necessary policy rules as `PreUp` commands in the server's WireGuard config files:

```
# /etc/wireguard/office1.conf
[Interface]
PrivateKey = 123ABC...
Address = 192.168.0.1/32
ListenPort = 51821
Table = 111

PreUp = ip rule add iif office1 table 111 priority 101
PostDown = ip rule del iif office1 table 111 priority 101

[Peer]
PublicKey = 123DEF...
AllowedIPs = 192.168.0.10/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = 123GHI...
AllowedIPs = 192.168.0.11/32
```

```
# /etc/wireguard/office2.conf
[Interface]
PrivateKey = 234ABC...
Address = 192.168.0.2/32
ListenPort = 51822
Table = 222

PreUp = ip rule add iif office2 table 222 priority 102
PostDown = ip rule del iif office2 table 222 priority 102

[Peer]
PublicKey = 234DEF...
AllowedIPs = 192.168.0.10/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = 234GHI...
AllowedIPs = 192.168.0.11/32
```

The `Table` setting in the above config files tells wg-quick to use the named routing table when adding the routes corresponding to each peer's `AllowedIPs` setting. The `PreUp` command adds a policy routing rule to use that table when routing incoming connections from the matching WireGuard interface (and the `PostDown` command removes the rule).

If the server ever needs to initiate connections to another host in one of the WireGuard networks, it would need to explicitly use its interface or address in that WireGuard network to trigger the correct policy rule; for example, to ping a host in the above `office1` network, you would need to specify the server's WireGuard address in that network (`192.168.0.1`):

```
ping -I 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.10
```

Also, you'd need to make sure the firewall on the server allows connections to be forwarded among the hosts in each WireGuard network (eg something like `iptables -A FORWARD -i office1 -o office1 -j ACCEPT` if you want to allow unrestricted forwarding between `office1` hosts).

---

However, if the server needs to use the same address for each WireGuard network (eg `192.168.0.1` for OFFICE_1 as well as `192.168.0.1` for OFFICE_2, etc), then you can't avoid using some form of containerization. The lightest-weight version of this is simply to create a separate network namespace for each WireGuard interface.

The "Ordinary Containerization" section of the [WireGuard Routing & Network Namespace Integration](https://www.wireguard.com/netns/#ordinary-containerization) guide demonstrates this with a neat trick that avoids having to do any port-forwarding on the server (by creating each WireGuard interface in the root namespace, and then moving it into a custom namespace).

The downside of using network namespaces (instead of full containers) is that you can't use wg-quick to help you -- you have to manually run a few of the iproute2 commands that wg-quick would normally run for you to set up the WireGuard interface.